# UITableViewCells invisible

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

**Requirement :**

I have a list of `UITableviewCell` loaded from a `nib` that I'm presenting on `UITableview`. The first time I open the `UIViewController` all cells are shown correctly and work as expected.

**Issue :**

If I navigate back to the parent and then open the `UIViewController` again the `UITableviewCell` are 'invisible'. I say invisible because with a breakpoint in `cellForRowAt` I can see that the table view does load all cells and the cells are valid.

**Code :**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 13
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = (project?.sliderData.sliders[indexPath.row].view)! as UITableViewCell
    print(cell.contentView.subviews.count)
    if let left = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UILabel {
        left.text = "left"
    }
    if let middle = cell.viewWithTag(3) as? UILabel {
        middle.text = "middle"
    }
    if let right = cell.viewWithTag(4) as? UILabel {
        right.text = "right"
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Screen Shot Image**

[image]

**Expected observation :**

I was thinking that maybe the `subviews` of the `cells` get released because I don't have any bindings to them in `IB`. To test this I'm **printing the count of subviews** and writing some text to the `subview` `labels`. And everything seems to go fine, the cells are loaded and the labels are there but the cells just don't show up.

But then, if I scroll the `TableView` up and down a little to get some cells updated those cells do appear at the top and bottom of the view as shown in the pic.

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like only top and bottom cells are loaded if you scroll the tableView but the cells which are in the middle of tableview are not visible. Is it correct? Have you tried calling tableView setNeedsDisplay() to paint the tableview again.

Comment: if I scroll the tableView the cells that enter the visible area are shown i.e. the ones that are reloaded, so by bouncing the top I can get couple of items visible. I tried adding setNeedsDisplay() at viewDidAppear but that has no effect.

Comment: Why are you not registering the nib and dequeuing the cells in the usual way?

Comment: I wanted to try a concept where a data class can provide its UI presentation but loads it only if requested. The slider object has an optional view property that is normally nil but if is used the getter will create the view. I guess this is not a valid way to load views?

Comment: It's perfectly valid to lazy load subviews - and you should be able to achieve that with dequeued cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find reason why the tableView behaves the way it does so I solved the issue by dequeueing default cells. The views provided by the slider objects are added as subviews to the dequeued cells. Now the subviews can of course be any UIViews.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sliderCell")
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "sliderCell")
    }
    cell?.addSubview((project?.sliderData.sliders[indexPath.row].view)!)
    return cell!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")` inside your code then will show your table cell. It will reuse cell for your all numbers of row data content.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UITableViewCell
   return cell
}
```

---

More Details : [How to create uitableview with multiple sections in iOS Swift.](http://blog.apoorvmote.com/uitableview-with-multiple-sections-ios-swift/)